# Рекурсивная функция с аргументами в виде структур

Tags: c, функции, рекурсия, структуры

Здравствуйте. Недавно был на собеседовании по C и попался один вопрос, который я не смог решить, но он меня заинтересовал.

Вопрос: переименуйте название функции на то, которое будет отображать её смысл, и аргументируйте свой выбор.

```
int f(struct n *p, struct n *q) 
{  
    int i = 0;
    if (p != NULL && q != NULL)
        i = (p->data == q->data) + f(p->left, q->left) + f(p->right, q->right);
    return i;
 }
```

Также объясните, какое определение должна иметь структура `n` и как вообще работает эта функция.

По идее структура должна быть такой, как показано ниже, но тогда подразумевается рекурсия в структурах?

```
struct n
{
    int data;
    struct n *right;
    struct n *left;
};
```

Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по виду, обычное бинарное дерево, а функция рекурсивно выясняет, сколько узлов в этом дереве совпадает (в смысле совпадения поля данных `data`) - сравнивает значения в текущих узлах, а затем - рекурсивно - в левом и правом поддеревьях.

Структура у вас указана верно (ну, разве что `data` - не обязательно `int`).

А название... Ну, что-то типа `count_of_matching_nodes`, например... Тут полет фантазии ограничен только знанием английского и степенью детализации функциональности в названии :)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А где могут использоваться такие деревья, не подскажете?

Comment: Просто бинарные деревья? Где угодно - это очень распространенная структура данных. В основном при реализации быстрой вставки с поиском, например, для реализации множеств или отображений.